# ERROR: Attempted to write schema for bad QName

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, axis

I'm trying to import a Java axis web service into C# to be used in my application; however, it is giving me the following error: Attempted to write schema for bad QName

Any idea what this could be?  I've imported schema before no problem, but this one won't budge.

Also, it's important to note that whenever I click the link to the WSDL file for this web service I get an HTTP 500 error.  Whenever I click any other WSDL web service link in the group it goes right to the WSDL schema page.  Obviously these two incidents are connected... I'm just not sure how.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 500 error is your problem.  If you can get a local copy of the wsdl/schemas you should be able to bring them into your c# application.  If you cannot browse to the WSDL c# is not going to be able to suck in the wsdl/schemas and generate the appropriate client code.